# Why doesn't matlab give me an 8KHz sinewave for 16KHz sampling frequency?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, sampling, trigonometry

I have the following matlab code, and I am trying to get 64 samples of various sinewave frequencies at 16KHz sampling frequency:

```
close all; clear; clc;
dt=1/16000;
freq = 8000;
t=-dt;
for i=1:64,
t=t+dt;a(i)=sin(2*pi*freq*t);
end
plot(a,'-o'); grid on;
```

for freq = 1000, the output graph is
[image]

The graph seems normal upto 2000, but at 3000, the graph is
[image]

We can see that the amplitude changes during every cycle

Again, at 4000 the graph is
[image]

Not exactly a sinewave, but the amplitude is as expected during every cycle and if I play it out it sounds like a single frequency tone

But again at 6000 we have
[image]

and at 8000 we have
[image]

Since the sampling frequency is 16000 I was assuming that I should be able to generate sinewave samples for upto 8000, and I was expecting the graph I got at 4000 to appear at 8000. Instead, even at 3000, the graph starts to look weird

If I change the sampling frequency to 32000 and the sinewave frequency to 16000, I get the same graph that I am getting now at 8000. Why does matlab behave this way?

EDIT:

at freq = 7900
[image]

Comment: Just for fun plot the `cos` next to the `sin` and you'll see something at 8kHz.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is just an artifact of aliasing. Notice how the vertical axis for the 8kHz graph only goes up to 1.5E-13? Ideally the graph should be all zeros; what you're seeing is rounding error.

Looking at the expression for computing the samples at 16kHz:

```
x(n) = sin(2 * pi * freq * n / 16000)
```

Where `x` is the signal, `n` is the integer sample number, and `freq` is the frequency in hertz. So, when `freq` is 8kHz, it's equivalent to:

```
x(n) = sin(2 * pi * 8000 * n / 16000) = sin(pi * n)
```

Because `n` is an integer, `sin(pi * n)` will always be zero. 8kHz is called the *Nyquist* frequency for a sampling rate of 16kHz for this reason; in general, the Nyquist frequency is always half the sample frequency.

At 3kHz, the signal "looks weird" because some of the peaks are at non-integer multiples of 16kHz, because 16 is not evenly divisible by 3. Same goes for the 6kHz signal.

The reason they still sound like pure sine tones is because of how the amplitude is *interpolated* between samples. The graph uses simple linear interpolation, which gives the impression of harsh edges at the samples. However, a physical loudspeaker (more precisely, the circuitry which drives it) does not use linear interpolation directly. Instead, a small filter circuit is used to smooth out those harsh edges (aka *anti-aliasing*) which removes the artificial frequencies above the aforementioned Nyquist frequency.

Comment: Does this mean I won't be able to get the sample for an 8K sinewave as long as I am working at 16K sampling frequency? I thought if the sampling frequency was at least double the maximum frequency present in the input, it would be enough to recreate the input from it's samples. I assumed this meant I should be able to get samples for sinewaves upto 8kHz for a 16kHz sampling frequency. Where did I go wrong about this?

Comment: It's a boundary case; with a 16K sample rate, you can get up to, but *not* including, 8K, for the very reason I demonstrated with all zeros at 8K. Frequencies just below 8K are technically fine, but start to look like they fade in and out.

Comment: Then can we determine the maximum frequency samples that can be generated at 16kHz? Is anything less than 8kHz possible? I will add the graph to 7900 to the question

Comment: This is clearly not a sinewave, but not 0 either. Can this also be explained by limitations of interpolating in matlab? Will playing it out still sound like a pure tone, due to reasons you described above?

Comment: I don't recall the exact formula, but it's basically a function of the total number of samples that gives the highest frequency you can accurately reconstruct. Something on the order of `8000 - 8000 / numberOfSamples`

Comment: As far as interpolation, I'm not too familiar with MatLab, but I'm sure there's a setting for changing the interpolation used on the graphs. As far as how it sounds, I believe as you get closer to 8K, it will actually start to sound like an 8K tone fading in and out.

Answer (score 0):

That is problem of matlab but a nature of sampling.

16KHz sampling makes 16K (16,000) sampled data per second. 8KHz signal has 8K (8000) cycles per second. So  two sample data per a cycle.

Two is minimum number of data per cycle. This is know a part of "sampling theorem".

Let try to show two cycles with three points on graph, you may understand that its impossible to show two cycles by three points. In the same way, you can't show 2N cycles by (2N-1) points.

Answer (score 0):

The effect seen for 8 kHz is as all other answers already mention aliasing effects and arises due to that the sine wave for 8 kHz is `sin(2*pi*n*8000*1/16000) = sin(n*pi)`, which is explained in [Drew McGovens answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25658208/2903371). Luckily the **amplitude** is not the only parameter that defines the signal. The other parameter that is required to completely define the signal is the **phase**. This means that when doing for fourier analysis of the signal, it is still possible to find the right frequency. Try:

```
close all; clear; clc;
dt=1/16000;
freq = 7300;
t=-dt;
for i=1:64,
    t=t+dt;a(i)=sin(2*pi*freq*t);
end
plot(a,'-o'); grid on;
figure; plot( linspace(1,16000,1000), abs(fft(a)) );
```

A side comment: some people might argue against using `i` as index variable since that can also be used as the imagiary number i. Personally I have nothing against using `i` since the runtime and overhead only is affected slightly and I always uses `1i`. However, just make sure to use `1i` consistently for the imaginary unit then.